# Flip JQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, flip

I'm making a website for a project, and I discovered and decided to use the, [jquery flip plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/), and it's not working... I did manage to get it working a while ago, but couldn't since. Bear in mind I have not yet made the grafic part of the website yet, so what's there is just for show.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/holythunder/mNQJB/) the source code for the website.

No errors, just not working (fliping said boxes). As I said, it worked before, but when I added those other boxes, it stopped working.

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very descriptive. Are you getting any errors? Did you check the console?

Comment: In what way is it not working? You should try to provide a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) instead of a pastebin to make it easier for people to help you. Also, in your code, you include the flip plugin js file twice - try removing one of those and see if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include jQuery UI before the Flip plugin. Since the Flip plugin needs jQuery UI to be available it probably fails when it's not.

It's always a good idea to use the demos on the plugin's documentation website as a template. The flip plugin includes the JS files in this order:

```
    <script src="/lab/flip/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lab/flip/js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
```

Also, in your JSFIddle, you have to use absolute URLs for the resources, JSFiddle doesn't magically find `jquery/jquery.flip.min.js`.

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle, I grabbed the above files from the plugin's documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/mNQJB/2/

If the above didn't fix your problem, there was an error with your code, one of the `.flip` calls had an invalid `content` property:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Make sure that your `content` properties are all on a single line or you have escaped the end-line characters properly.

### Update

To escape an end-line character in JS we do this:

```
var str = "This is a string and \
I want it to use two lines.";
```

Notice the backslash, it's the standard escaping character. Now if you want to create a new line that will be rendered via HTML then you should use a `<br />` tag:

```
var str = "This is a string and <br />I want it to use two lines.";
```

Comment: Just changed it, and updated my fiddle, it's still not working.

Comment: @HolyThunderz did you see my jsfiddle? It's an updated version of yours (and it works). The main issue you were having is that you had a string that had an end-line character that wasn't escaped that was stopping the execution of the JS.

Comment: @HolyThunderz On a side-note, this did output an error, and you can catch that error using your Developer Tools. If you aren't using your console then I suggest you get used to doing so, it will save you tons of time debugging. Most browsers let you open your developer tools by pressing F12.

Comment: Oh, thanks alot! What can I do to make it work without removing that part? I shouldn't cut on the text.

Comment: @HolyThunderz Well if you want to force a new line in HTML then use a `<br />` tag, if you want to use an end-line character then escape it with a `\`. I'll add a quick example to my answer.

Comment: Your updated version gives me a 404 now, could you please show it to me somehow so I could see it?

Comment: Oh, I just found made it work, thanks dude! Really helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
you have an unterminated string constant in this section:

 $("#aimsb").bind("click",function(){
        $("#aims").flip({
            direction: 'bt',
            color: '#39AB3E',
            content: 'The aims of the GSP (Global Student Project) are to give students from all around the world both a culturally and personally enriching experience, as well as equal learning, and subsquently job opportunities
            .'
        });
    });
```

note the line feed prior to the `.'`

Comment: NOTE: this is to cleary deliniate the answer provided by Jasper - that is the correct answer, this just adds details.

Comment: Good details too, I was going to post this but you beat me to it!