# Html/CSS/Javascript Function to flip image is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, flip

I have to flip an image in my project and im using a function in combination with css to implement it. When it's flipped, it shows another div en when flipped again ofcourse back to the original div. But when I click nothing happens. So something is still wrong, but no idea what.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

      $('.sponsorFlip').bind("click", function () {

          // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

          var elem = $(this);

          // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:

          if (elem.data('flipped')) {
              // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
              // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:

              elem.revertFlip();

              // Unsetting the flag:
              elem.data('flipped', false);
          }
          else {
              // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

              elem.flip({
                  direction: 'lr',
                  speed: 350,
                  onBefore: function () {
                      // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden from view with display:none)
                      // into the clicked .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                      elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
                  }
              });

              // Setting the flag:
              elem.data('flipped', true);
          }
      });

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sponsorListHolder">
            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip" >
                    <img src="Images/edan.png" alt="More about Edan" id="test" />
                </div>
                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">
                        Edan
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">
                        <!--                    <a href="#">Edan</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sponsorListHolder{
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.sponsor{
width:180px;
height:180px;
float:left;
margin:4px;

/* Giving the sponsor div a relative positioning: */
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
}

.sponsorFlip{
/*  The sponsor div will be positioned absolutely with respect
    to its parent .sponsor div and fill it in entirely */

position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:1px solid #ddd;  

}

.sponsorFlip:hover{
border:1px solid #999;

/* CSS3 inset shadow: */
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 30px #999 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 30px #999 inset;
box-shadow:0 0 30px #999 inset;
}

.sponsorFlip img{
/* Centering the logo image in the middle of the sponsorFlip div */

position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-70px 0 0 -70px;
}

.sponsorData{
/* Hiding the .sponsorData div */
display:none;
}

.sponsorDescription{
font-size:11px;
padding:50px 10px 20px 20px;
font-style:italic;
}

.sponsorURL{
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:20px;
}
```

I have included the jquery plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
```

Greets

Comment: Are you using the flip plugin http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ ?

Comment: You may create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have added the Jquery, and you may also add the [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
```

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ On the right side, it mentions that this plugin depends on Jquery and Jquery UI.

Hope it works.

Comment: That should help, but It still doesn't work.Any other idea's?

Comment: I tried your code on my computer, added the js packages. The order of the js packages: jquery first, then jquery ui and finally flip. I have tested on the chrome, ie9 and firefox. Pay attention to IE, script may be banned. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268128/flip-jquery-plugin-not-working)